# NextJS MDXRemote element override not working for images?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using MDX with NextJS. I can override heading elements successfully.

In my MDX:

```
###### This is an h6
```

In my React component:

```
const CustomH6 = ({ children }) => {
  return <h6 style={{ background: "gold" }}>{children}</h6>;
};


<MDXRemote
  {...props.content}
  components={{
    h6: CustomH6,
  }}
/>
```

However I can't get this working for image elements.

I've tried using a regular image in my MDX:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="alt text" />
```

But the 'CustomImage' isn't used and the image renders normal.

```
<MDXRemote
  {...props.content}
  components={{
    img: CustomImage,
  }}
/>
```

I also tried using the markdown syntax for the image:

```
![alt text](/image.jpg)
```

Then it does work but I get an error in the webpage:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Comment: What are the contents of your CustomImage?